# swimlane ngx line chart second y axis in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I'm trying to create an line chart in my angular project, where i have two y axis.
Since I am not very skilled in this area I have tinkered an example, by manipulating the comboBarScheme domain:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-combo-chart-knzxbc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Is there a way to hide the bars without causing an error?  Or is there a similar simple solution to have two y axes in one line chart?

I think my ducktape solution is extremely short-sighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing   `showGridLines = true;` from app.component.ts or set like this    `showGridLines = false;`

Comment: Hi, I want my Y axis in Line chart to start from min 5 and no max value...I used [yScaleMin] = "5" then it decreased from 5 to 0 up the scale. ONce I define both [yScaleMin] = "5" [yScaleMax] = "50" its going 5 to 50, but can I exclude the max value or override the transform function?